# Showing list of objects in GUI using Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a program that populates lists based on user input. These lists are actually lists of objects that have 2 values: name and amount.

I'm currently running tkinter and trying to return these lists in a readable format in the GUI.  Here's what I have so far:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

Containers =[]
Lids = []
Wicks = []
Labels = []
Misc = []
Items = [Containers, Lids, Wicks, Labels, Misc]

class item(object):

    #Constructor
    def __init__(self, name, amount):
        self.name = name
        self.amount = amount

    #Accessors
    def getName(self):
        return self.name

    def getAmount(self):
        return self.amount

def addItem(*args):
    s = name.get()
    global new_item
    new_item = item(s, 0)
    return new_item
    Containers.append(new_item) 

name = StringVar()
amount = StringVar()
remove_item = StringVar()
add_amount = StringVar()
subtract_amount = StringVar()

   ...#Leaving out all the frame information

t = Text(mainframe, width=60)
for item in Containers:
    t.insert(END, item)
t.grid(column = 1, columnspan = 3, row = 10, padx = 5, pady = 10)

root.bind('<Return>', addItem())

root.mainloop()
```

What happens when I try to run the following is that I get an error: 'item' object is not callable

```
t = Text(mainframe, width=60)
    for item in Containers:
        t.insert(END, item)
    t.grid(column = 1, columnspan = 3, row = 10, padx = 5, pady = 10)
```

How can I print these lists in the main GUI window?

Comment: show full error message (Traceback). BTW: use CamelCase names for class (`class Item(object)`) and lower_case names for variables (`containers`)  It helps recegnize classes in code. You use `item` as class name and later as variable in `for item`. It can make problem.

Comment: In `addItem` you return before even adding it to the list. `root.bind('<Return>', addItem())` is calling the function and returning an item object not binding the function, this is most likely the issue. `root.bind('<Return>', addItem)` is what you want

Comment: I figured it out with the root.bind().  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your bind:

```
root.bind('<Return>', addItem())
```

When this line is evaluated addItem will return an item object at- `return new_item` - and when you hit return python will try to call new_item. What you wrote is essentially:

```
new_item = additem()
root.bind('<Return>', new_item)
```

And there is no reason at all to use a global var if you're returning the item. What you meant is :

```
root.bind('<Return>', addItem)
```

so when you hit return the function addItem is called. Here you might think you need the global var but there are probably better ways, like encapsulating your entire application in a class.
You have a lot of wrong in your code, so I suggest you work on it some before asking better questions. For example:

```
Containers.append(new_item)
```

is never called because it is after a return, also you have yet to put an input field which is what you probably meant to bind, not root, so actual input can be given. Google some Tk examples.